django multiple database settingup for multiple region
Issue with Django DatabaseRouter and Related Models
I'm working on a Django project with multiple regional databases. I'm facing an issue where fetching an employee object with a related model from a different database results in the related model being retrieved from the default database instead of the intended regional database.
Setup

Two regional databases (us and potentially others)

DatabaseRouter to route models to their respective databases

The issue occurs when trying to prefetch or access related models using foreign key relationships


Shell Plus Model Imports
>>> employee = Employees.objects.using('us').get(employee_id='ORG-EMP-1001')
SELECT "general_employees"."org_id_id",
      "general_employees"."first_name",
 FROM "general_employees"
 WHERE "general_employees"."employee_id" = 'ORG-EMP-1001'
 LIMIT 21
Execution time: 0.306803s [Database: us]

>>> organisation = Organisation.objects.using('us').get(pk=employee.org_id.pk)
SELECT "general_organisation"."onboard_id",
      "general_organisation"."org_id",
      "general_organisation"."zip_code",
 FROM "general_organisation"
 WHERE "general_organisation"."org_id" = 'ORG-FFZN5OFF'
 LIMIT 21
Execution time: 0.021803s [Database: default]

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/sshva/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 187, in __get__
   rel_obj = self.field.get_cached_value(instance)
 File "/Users/sshva/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/mixins.py", line 15, in get_cached_value
   return instance._state.fields_cache[cache_name]
KeyError: 'org_id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Users/sshva/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 205, in __get__
   rel_obj = self.get_object(instance)
 File "/Users/sshva/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 168, in get_object
   return qs.get(self.field.get_reverse_related_filter(instance))
 File "/Users/sshva/Documents/newenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 496, in get
general.models.Organisation.DoesNotExist: Organisation matching query does not exist.

class DatabaseRouter:
   def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
       if 'database' in hints:
           return hints['database']
       if model._meta.app_label == 'common':
           return 'common'
       return 'default'

   def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
       if 'database' in hints:
           return hints['database']
       if model._meta.app_label == 'common':
           return 'common'
       return 'default'

   def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
       if obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db:
           return True
       return False

   def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
       if db == 'common' and app_label != 'common':
           return False
       if db != 'common' and app_label == 'common':
           return False
       return True

   def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
       if 'prefetch_related' in hints:
           return True
       return obj1._state.db == obj2._state.db

